# How would I include values from one list as a range for an if statement, in another list?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've started looking into tkinter with python recently, and have started making a mario-esque style game, involving a player (rectangle) moving around, colliding with platforms and such and collecting coins.

My detection system for the player hitting the ground involves the *.find_overlapping method of the players co-ordinates, and if they are overlapping the ground, or another platform per say, then it sets the players y co-ordinates to be on top of the said object.

```
def collide():
    playerBox = screen.find_overlapping(screen.coords(player)[0], screen.coords(player)[1]
                                  , screen.coords(player)[2], screen.coords(player)[3])

    if  playerBox in [(1, 3)]:
        screen.coords(player, screen.coords(player)[0], screen.coords(root.floor)[1] - defaultHeight
                        , screen.coords(player)[2], screen.coords(root.floor)[1])
```

(This is where the (1, 3) returned overlap represents the player overlapping with the ground (floor), and the defaultHeight is 56 if you wish to know, so that the players height remains constant.)

However, if the player is in contact with a coin, then they fall through the ground, and stay below the surface. To fix this, I have the object initiation list (made from a dictionary created alongside the actual coins creation) of the coins made which looks like:

```
coinList = [4, 5, 6...] #For however many coins are made (As the first coin is the fourth object on screen, this may change though)
```

I want to be able to include this coinList into the if statement shown above, something like:

```
if  playerBox in [(1, 3), (1, 3, coinList)]:
```

This is not working however, and I cannot understand why or how this could work.

I am open to any other suggestions you may have for solving this problem!

Thanks in advance.

PS: Sorry if my post formatting is wrong or doesn't contain enough information, feel free to ask for more info if needed.

Comment: Can you give an example of what `playerBox` would be (A value ? A list containing a value? A list containing a tuple?) and what you would your `in ...` clause to look like (like, let's say, `[(1, 3), (1, 3, 4, 5, 6)]`)? I am not too sure what you really want to obtain as a result to be honest :)

Comment: If you are using Python 3.x, then all you need to do is write `if  playerBox in [(1, 3), (1, 3, *coinList)]:` *star will unpuck the list to the tuple. (If this is what u want)

Answer (score 0):

`find_overlapping` returns tuple of objects which overlap player rect. You have to compare every element one-by-one

```
playerBox = screen.find_overlapping(*screen.coords(player))

all_elements = [1, 3] + coinList  

found = False
for x in playerBox:
    if x in all_elements:
       found = True
       break

if found:
   screen.coords(player, ...)
```

Or you can use `set()`

```
playerBox = screen.find_overlapping(*screen.coords(player))

all_elements = [1, 3] + coinList  

if set(playerBox) & set(all_elements):
    screen.coords(player, ...)
```